# Rust Vulkano creation of compute pipeline does not work and freeze my video card

Tags: rust, graphics, glsl, vulkan, compute-shader

I'm trying to load a shader into an amd video card. After all the buffers are created, I try to create a new Compute pipeline. As i started to debug it printing messages i found out that the "Finished Creating the compute pipeline" is never printed. When i run it with `cargo run --release` it prints the: "Creating pipeline with shader" but after some seconds it freezes my whole computer and i have to turn it off and back on again...

My Vulkano version is: 0.32.1;
My vulkano-shaders version is: 0.32.1;
My Video Card is: AMD RX570 4GB

Vulkano Physical device properties:

```rust
buffer_image_granularity: 64,
compute_units_per_shader_array: Some(
    8,
),
conformance_version: Some(
    1.2.0,
),
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "vulkano_matrix"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
vulkano = "0.32.1"
vulkano-shaders = "0.32.0"
rand = "0.8.4"
nalgebra="0.31.4"
colored = "2.0.0"
bytemuck = "1.12.3"
```

```rust
// main.rs
extern crate nalgebra as na;
use bytemuck::{Pod, Zeroable};
use colored::Colorize;
use na::{dmatrix, DMatrix};
use std::{
    io::{stdin, stdout, Write},
    sync::Arc,
    time::Instant,
};
use vulkano::{
    buffer::{BufferUsage, CpuAccessibleBuffer, DeviceLocalBuffer},
    command_buffer::{
        allocator::{CommandBufferAllocator, StandardCommandBufferAllocator},
        AutoCommandBufferBuilder, PrimaryAutoCommandBuffer, PrimaryCommandBufferAbstract,
    },
    descriptor_set::{
        allocator::StandardDescriptorSetAllocator, PersistentDescriptorSet, WriteDescriptorSet,
    },
    device::{
        physical::PhysicalDevice, Device, DeviceCreateInfo, DeviceExtensions, Features,
        QueueCreateInfo, QueueFlags,
    },
    instance::{Instance, InstanceCreateInfo},
    memory::allocator::{MemoryAllocator, StandardMemoryAllocator},
    pipeline::Pipeline,
    pipeline::{ComputePipeline, PipelineBindPoint},
    sync::GpuFuture,
    VulkanLibrary,
};

#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub enum Padding {
    None,
    Fixed(usize, usize),
    Same,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Default, Copy, Clone, Debug, Zeroable, Pod)]
struct Dimension {
    pub rows: usize,
    pub columns: usize,
    pub channels: usize,
}

impl Dimension {
    pub fn from_matrix<T>(mat: &DMatrix<T>) -> Self {
        let shape = mat.shape();
        Self {
            rows: shape.0,
            columns: shape.1,
            channels: 1,
        }
    }
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Default, Copy, Clone, Debug, Zeroable, Pod)]
struct BufferDimensions {
    pub input_matrix: Dimension,
    pub kernel: Dimension,
    pub output_matrix: Dimension,
}

#[repr(C)]
#[derive(Default, Copy, Clone, Debug, Zeroable, Pod)]
struct ConvolutionOptions {
    pub padding: [i32; 2],
    pub stride: u32,
}

fn input(question: impl Into<String>) -> String {
    let mut result = "".to_string();
    print!("{} ", question.into().bold().cyan());
    stdout().flush().expect("Could not flush stdout");
    stdin()
        .read_line(&mut result)
        .expect("Could not read stdin");
    result
}

fn main() {
    let library = VulkanLibrary::new().expect("Could not find vulkan.dll");
    let instance =
        Instance::new(library, InstanceCreateInfo::default()).expect("Failed to Create Instance");

    println!("Available GPUs:");
    let physical_devices = instance
        .enumerate_physical_devices()
        .expect("Could not enumerate the physical devices")
        .enumerate()
        .map(|(i, physical)| {
            println!(
                "[{}]: \"{}\"; TYPE: \"{:?}\"; API_VERSION: \"{}\"",
                i.to_string().bold().bright_magenta(),
                physical.properties().device_name.to_string().bold().green(),
                physical.properties().device_type,
                physical.api_version()
            );
            physical
        })
        .collect::<Vec<Arc<PhysicalDevice>>>();

    let physical_index = input(format!("Type the chosen [{}]:", "index".bright_magenta()))
        .replace("\n", "")
        .parse::<usize>()
        .expect("Please type a number.");
    let physical = physical_devices[physical_index].clone();
    println!(
        "Using {}; TYPE: \"{:?}\"; \n\n {:?} \n\n {:#?}",
        physical.properties().device_name.to_string().bold().green(),
        physical.properties().device_type,
        physical.api_version(),
        physical.properties()
    );
    return;

    let queue_family_index = physical
        .queue_family_properties()
        .iter()
        .position(|q| {
            q.queue_flags.intersects(&QueueFlags {
                compute: true,
                ..QueueFlags::empty()
            })
        })
        .unwrap() as u32;

    let (device, mut queues) = Device::new(
        physical,
        DeviceCreateInfo {
            enabled_features: Features::empty(),
            queue_create_infos: vec![QueueCreateInfo {
                queue_family_index,
                ..Default::default()
            }],
            ..Default::default()
        },
    )
    .expect("Failed to create device");
    let queue = queues.next().unwrap();

    let memory_allocator = StandardMemoryAllocator::new_default(device.clone());
    let descriptor_set_allocator = StandardDescriptorSetAllocator::new(device.clone());
    let command_buffer_allocator =
        StandardCommandBufferAllocator::new(device.clone(), Default::default());

    let mut builder = AutoCommandBufferBuilder::primary(
        &command_buffer_allocator,
        queue.queue_family_index(),
        vulkano::command_buffer::CommandBufferUsage::OneTimeSubmit,
    )
    .unwrap();

    let stride = 1;
    let get_result_shape = |input_shape: usize, padding: usize, ker_shape: usize| {
        (input_shape + 2 * padding - ker_shape) / stride + 1
    };
    let padding = Padding::Same;

    let input_data = dmatrix![1.0f32, 2., 3.; 4., 5., 6.; 7., 8., 9.];
    let kernel_data = dmatrix![11.0f32, 19.; 31., 55.];
    let input_shape = Dimension::from_matrix(&input_data);
    let kernel_shape = Dimension::from_matrix(&kernel_data);

    let padding = match padding {
        Padding::None => (0, 0),
        Padding::Fixed(x_p, y_p) => (x_p, y_p),
        Padding::Same => {
            let get_padding = |input_shape: usize, ker_shape: usize| {
                (((stride - 1) as i64 * input_shape as i64 - stride as i64 + ker_shape as i64)
                    as f64
                    / 2.0)
                    .ceil() as usize
            };
            (
                /* rows */
                get_padding(input_shape.rows, kernel_shape.rows),
                /* columns */
                get_padding(input_shape.columns, kernel_shape.columns),
            )
        }
    };

    let dimensions = BufferDimensions {
        input_matrix: input_shape,
        kernel: kernel_shape,
        output_matrix: Dimension {
            rows: get_result_shape(input_shape.rows, padding.0, kernel_shape.rows),
            columns: get_result_shape(input_shape.columns, padding.1, kernel_shape.columns),
            channels: 1,
        },
    };
    let options = ConvolutionOptions {
        padding: [padding.0 as i32, padding.1 as i32],
        stride: stride as u32,
    };

    let dimensions_buffer = DeviceLocalBuffer::from_data(
        &memory_allocator,
        dimensions,
        BufferUsage {
            uniform_buffer: true,
            ..BufferUsage::empty()
        },
        &mut builder,
    )
    .expect("Failed to create uniform buffer.");
    let options_buffer = DeviceLocalBuffer::from_data(
        &memory_allocator,
        options,
        BufferUsage {
            uniform_buffer: true,
            ..BufferUsage::empty()
        },
        &mut builder,
    )
    .expect("Failed to create uniform buffer.");

    println!(
        "{:?} {:?} {:?} {:?}",
        input_data, dimensions, options, kernel_data
    );

    let input_buffer = DeviceLocalBuffer::from_iter(
        &memory_allocator,
        input_data.data.as_vec().to_owned(),
        BufferUsage {
            uniform_buffer: true,
            ..BufferUsage::empty()
        },
        &mut builder,
    )
    .expect("Failed to create uniform buffer.");
    let kernel_buffer = DeviceLocalBuffer::from_iter(
        &memory_allocator,
        kernel_data.data.as_vec().to_owned(),
        BufferUsage {
            uniform_buffer: true,
            ..BufferUsage::empty()
        },
        &mut builder,
    )
    .expect("Failed to create uniform buffer.");
    let output_buffer = CpuAccessibleBuffer::from_iter(
        &memory_allocator,
        BufferUsage {
            storage_buffer: true,
            ..BufferUsage::empty()
        },
        false,
        [0..(dimensions.output_matrix.channels
            * dimensions.output_matrix.rows
            * dimensions.output_matrix.columns)]
        .map(|__| 0.0f32)
        .to_owned(),
    )
    .expect("Failed to create storage buffer.");

    println!("Loading shader");
    
let cs = cs::load(device.clone()).unwrap();

println!("Creating pipeline with shader"); // This line prints just fine 
let compute_pipeline = ComputePipeline::new(
    device.clone(),
    cs.entry_point("main").unwrap(),
    &(),
    None,
    |_| {},
)
.expect("Failed to create compute shader");
println!("Finished Creating the compute pipeline"); // THIS LINE NEVER GETS RUN

}


pub mod cs {
    use vulkano_shaders::shader;

    shader! {
        ty: "compute",
        path: "./matrix_convolution.glsl"
    }
}
```

The shader is:

```c
#version 450
#pragma shader_stage(compute)

layout(local_size_x=32, local_size_y=32, local_size_z=16) in;

struct Dimension {
  uint rows;
  uint columns;
  uint channels;
};

layout(set=0, binding=0) buffer Dimensions {
  Dimension input_matrix;
  Dimension kernel;
  Dimension output_matrix;
} dims_buf;


layout(set=0, binding=1) buffer readonly InputMatrix {
  float[] input_matrix;
};

layout(set=0, binding=2) buffer readonly Kernel {
  float[] kernel;
};


layout(set=0, binding=3) buffer writeonly OutputMatrix {
   float[] output_matrix;
}; 
layout(set=0, binding=4) buffer Options {
   ivec2 padding;
   uint stride;
} options_buf;

void main() {
  const uint raw_row = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x;
  const uint raw_column = gl_GlobalInvocationID.y;
  const uint raw_channel = gl_GlobalInvocationID.z;
}
```

I tried to run similar programs with different shaders and it worked just fine.

Comment: When asking for debugging help you should include a [mre], not just snippets of your code.

Comment: This is mot probably caused by wrong application behavior. Try running your application with Validation layers enabled and make sure they don't report any errors. If they do, post those errors here and we may be able to help.

Comment: I ran: `VK_INSTANCE_LAYERS=VK_LAYER_LUNARG_standard_validation cargo run` and nothing showed on the screen, it froze my screen for a couple of milliseconds but this time i did not have to restart my pc. Still tho, it never printed the line "Finished Creating the compute pipeline". and after some seconds it gets killed by the os

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the work groups sizes must be fewer less than the

Therefore: local_size_x * local_size_y * local_size_z must be less than max_compute_work_group_invocations

````rust
physical.properties().max_compute_work_group_invocations ```
````